# How to process this image for Pytesseract?

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract, pytesser

I want to solve automatically captchas like this one. I have been trying processing image to make Pytesseract be able to read it, but no success.

Can you help me?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJHX9.png)

I try this:

```
import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string
import pytesseract




img = cv2.imread("screenshot.png")
img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=16, fy=16)
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
gry = cv2.resize(gry, (w*2, h*2))
cls = cv2.morphologyEx(gry, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, None)
#thr = cv2.threshold(cls, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
txt = image_to_string(,lang='eng', config='--psm 11')
cv2.imwrite('prv.png', thr)
print(txt)
```

Comment: Captchas are **designed** to be hard to solve by computers... to stop idiots annoying sensible folk.

Comment: Sorry, I need it

Answer (score 0):

It would be really hard for AI/ML to solve a captcha. They are, at their core, designed to stop OCR.

Consider reading this:
https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/bots/how-captchas-work/

Comment: it is possible, I have seen many like these solved. I need someone who knows the cv2 library.